# Why the extra step: kubectl replace serviceaccount

Tags: kubernetes

In [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#add-imagepullsecrets-to-a-service-account) kubernetres documentation, why do you need the extra step replacing the `kubectl replace serviceaccount`?

I can see that the name of the `imagePullSecrets` is wrong alright, but I would expect `kubectl patch serviceaccount` to do this - well it does not, so there must be a reason?

Comment: I'd say you don't need the replace step. It's just two ways of doing the same thing? But I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

It's for the sake of convenience. Imagine you have several typical deployments that use the same serviceaccount and a number of images from Docker registry with authentication. By incorporating imagePullSecrets inside serviceaccount you can now specify only serviceAccountName in your deployments - imagePullSecrets will be automatically added.

I would not say this is a very cool feature, but in some cases it can be useful.